# leaflet js overwriting other EventListeners?

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, addeventlistener

How to open modal from svgOverlay in leaflet?

I have Open Street Maps integrated with leaflet with an svgElement as overlay. In my svg there are several  tags, and when clicking on these elements in the svg-overlay a javascript is set to open a modal. But nothing happens.

It seems like the EventListeners attached to the  tags disappear when I implement the svg within the leaflet integrated map.

Is leaflet js overwriting the EventListeners written by the modal js?

Within the inspector, I have checked that the full svg code (including the -elements) are loaded.

Comment: Probably a timing issue ! You need to make sure that your SVG element is existing at the moment you want to add your event listener.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.